# Why WalkingFileTree is faster the second time?

Tags: java, windows, performance, filesystems

I am using the function `Files.walkfiletree()` from `java.NIO`, I am looking over a really big tree so when I run the app the first time (with first time I mean each time I turn on my computer)  the app takes some time but the second time is really fast.
why? is some cache working? Can I use this in some permanent way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read data from the filesystem, that information is caching making accessing it again much faster.  In some cases 100x faster or more.  It caches the data in memory because it is faster.

The simplest solution is to access/load this directory structure before you need it and you will get cached performance. e.g. you can do this on start up.

Another solution is to get a faster SSD.  Accessing file structures performs a lot of disk operations to get all the pieces of information.  A HDD can do up to 120 IOPS, a cheap SSD can do 40,000 IOPS and a fast SSD can do 250,000 IOPS.  This can dramatically reduce the time to load this information.

However, since you cannot control what is in memory, except by accessing it repeatedly, it may be pushed out of the disk  cache later.

Comment: It was what I guessed, hope was some "java mechanism". I am looking over my company file system so over hundred of TB with HDD in RAID5. I was trying to avoid it but I will have to implement some index or DB.

Comment: @user3084798 Some sort of index you maintain sounds like a good idea.  HDD will only spin so fast and most RAID-5 systems are designed for throughput rather than improving random access, you might get around 400 IOPS in a typical HDD RAID-5.  If you can, store your DB on an SSD ;)

Comment: Cheers, you tell to my boss now ;).

Comment: @PeterRip You can buy a pair (for RAID-1) of 240 GB enterprise grade SSDs for £200 total, each doing 85,000 IOPS http://www.scan.co.uk/products/240gb-pny-prevail-25-ssd-sata-iii-6gb-s-sandforce-2281-mlc-flash-read-550mb-s-write-520mb-s-85000-io